# Access LinearLayout Subclass Parameter from Button Click

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a subclass called AuditQuestionEntry that extends LinearLayout. In addition to other fields, this layout contains a button. On my main activity ("AuditActivity") I have multiple instances of AuditQuestionEntry. From AuditActivity, I am setting an OnClickListener for the button in each of the AuditQuestionEntry layouts. In the OnClick method I need to access a parameter that's in the AuditQuestionEntry associated with the button that was clicked.

In the OnClickListener I call getParent() and I can cast that to AuditQuestionEntry. However, when I try to access a parameter from there it returns null (or 0 in my case because it's an int). Basically, it appears that getParent() is returning a new instance of the class and not the actual instance that contains the button.

**Layout - audit_question_entry.xml:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/auditQuestion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Audit Question..."
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTakeAuditPhoto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Photo" >
</Button>
```

**Here's the AuditQuestionEntry.java:**

```
public class AuditQuestionEntry extends LinearLayout {

// Define controls
private TextView auditQuestion;
private RatingBar auditRating;
private EditText auditComment;
private ImageView imageView;
private Button photoButton;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

public int AuditQuestionNumber; // NEED TO GET THIS!
private Context _ctx;

public ClosetAuditQuestionObj AuditQuestion;

private String PhotoFolder;
private String FullPhotoPathAndName;

public AuditQuestionEntry(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // InflateView();

    throw new RuntimeException("Valid AuditQuestionNumber must be passed to this class via the XML parameters: workbench:AuditQuestionNumber.");
}

public AuditQuestionEntry(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this._ctx = context;

    initAttributes(attrs);
}

// Used to grab the AuditQuestionNumber attribute from the XML declaration
// for this layout
private void initAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = _ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AuditQuestionEntry);

    AuditQuestionNumber = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.bc.workbench", "AuditQuestionNumber", 0);

    a.recycle();
}
```

**Inside AuditActivity onCreate() I have the following:**

```
         OnClickListener btnPhotoListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            View viewParent = (View) v.getParent();

            AuditQuestionEntry clickedAudit = (AuditQuestionEntry) viewParent;

            // On the following line, clickedAudit.AuditQuestionNumber is always 0 even though it was initialized and
            // displays properly on screen.
            Toast.makeText(CurrentContext, "Audit Question #" + clickedAudit.AuditQuestionNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

     };


        // Set event listener for photo buttons
        // =============================================
     ((Button) AuditQuestion1.findViewById(R.id.btnTakeAuditPhoto)).setOnClickListener(btnPhotoListener);
     ((Button) AuditQuestion2.findViewById(R.id.btnTakeAuditPhoto)).setOnClickListener(btnPhotoListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where in the XML are you setting the attribute for the AuditQuestionNumber?  The constructor is defaulting the value of the class attribute to 0 if the XML being used to inflate the class doesn't include the attribute:

```
AuditQuestionNumber = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.bc.workbench", "AuditQuestionNumber", 0);
```

Comment: The default constructor isn't called but the 2nd one with the AttributeSet parameters is called. Again, taking the button out of the question (without giving full details of the rest of the logic in this activity), the AuditQuestionNumber is in fact correctly being set and I can verify that by debugging and the other logic out of the scope of this question.

Comment: It's difficult to say what could be happening since there's not a complete picture of the code here.  Is there a chance something else is manipulating the <code>AuditQuestionNumber</code> attribute?  It's set as a public attribute, so anything could touch it.  Have you tried boiling this issue down in a simpler example?  Have you verified with the debugger that the AuditQuestionEntry object ID for a given button at creation matches the one returned when calling <code>getParent()</code>?  They should match.

Comment: Ok, so you've got me going down the right path. For some reason, my custom view (AuditQuestionEntry) constructor is being called twice and the 2nd time it isn't actually initializing attributes so the AuditQuestionNumber is 0 - hence my problem. My question now becomes why would the constructor be called twice?

Comment: Fundamental issue is that the call to setContentView effectively inflates the layout (and sets AuditQuestionNumber from the XML attribute), but I'm also calling the layout inflater from inside AuditQuestionEntry so I can set the controls (i.e. rating, labels, etc.).